# bootstrap 3 modal in MVC not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show a modal from bootstrap 3([here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples)) in my MVC application.
This is what i've done

```
@model DatePicker.Models.ViewModels.Appointment.CreateAppointmentSelectPersons
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
}
<button id="showDetail" class="btn btn-default">Next>></button>
<div id="appointmentModal" class="modal hide fade in" data-url="@Url.Action("Detail", "Appointment", new { appointmentId = Model.AppointmentId })">
    <div id="appointmentContainer"></div>
</div>

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")


    <script type="text/javascript">    

        $("#showDetail").click(function () {
            var url = $("#appointmentModal").data('url');
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('#appointmentContainer').html(data);
                $('#appointmentModal').modal(show);
            });
        })

    </script>
}
```

and in partial view

```
@model DatePicker.Models.ViewModels.Appointment.DetailsAppointment

<div class="modal fade" id="appointmentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="appointmentModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="appointmentModalLabel">Details</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h5>Your appointment is ready to be sent, please reveiew the details</h5>
                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <dt>Subject/Name</dt>
                    <dd>@Model.Name</dd>                  
                </dl>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in controller

```
   public ActionResult Detail(Guid appointmentId)
    {
        ....
        return PartialView(appointmentDetails);
    }
```

Here, when I click the Next>> button in view, my modal doesn't show.
but when I inspect the network part and see the preview section i can see that the data is being collected from my backend. Its just that modal is not showing.
What should i do?
[image]

Edit1:

Console error
[image]

Comment: DO you have any error on console?

Comment: yes it says show is not defined?

Comment: You are adding a modal with the same id's to an existing modal.

Comment: Have you tried putting show in commas like this: $('#appointmentModal').modal('show');

Comment: @Andrew I did it, not errors now and when i click the button background turns darker but modal doesn't pop up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made an error in JavaScript function. It should be like following:

```
   $("#showDetail").click(function () {
        var url = $("#appointmentModal").data('url');
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#appointmentContainer').html(data);
            $('#appointmentModal').modal('show');
        });
    })
```

The change is: `modal(show)` to ***modal('show')***